# C# Console App SOAP response is null

Tags: c#, soap

I've seen some questions very similar to mine, but they seem to be a few years old now, and I'm not sure if the same fixes apply.

Basically I have access to a SOAP service. I've added it as a Service Reference in my C# console app. I can establish a connection, but need a session ID before I can do anything. The Session ID is part of the response, but the response in C# is null. I've used Fiddler, and I can see that I'm successfully making a connection, and the response ID is there, but I can't get it to show in Visual Studio. Obviously the response is XML. Am I missing something? How do I capture that XML response in VS?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What response did the server send. Can you check that in Fiddler?

Comment: What does this have to do w/Java?

Comment: Please provide code example of what you are trying to achieve,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, at least in my experience, SOAP services return typed data. It will be defined by the service as string, datatable, etc. You need to determine the datatype and store the output from the SOAP service into that type.

Example:

string

```
string mystring = soapservice.getmystuff()
```

datatable

```
DataTable mydatatable = soapservice.getmystuff()
```

Then, once you have successfully stored the results in a typed object, manipulate that object to retrieve your data.